# Gremlin Python how to make by(values('name','score')) to work

Tags: gremlin

My test graph has this path: test_score -- belonged_to -> person.  I was able to get the following script to work.

```
graph = Graph()
conn = DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin', 'g')  # should learn to open a new graph
gr = graph.traversal().withRemote(conn)
print(gr.V().hasLabel("test_score").out("belonged_to").path().by("score").by("name").toList())
```

which printed out

> [[95, 'marko'], [95, 'vadas'], [88, 'vadas'], [85, 'marko'], [100,
>   'josh'], [80, 'vadas'], [80, 'josh'], [60, 'josh'], [75, 'marko']]

Vertex `test_score` had properties `'name'` and `'score'` and I liked to print out both properties.  I tried the following but line but it erred out.

```
print(gr.V().hasLabel("test_score").out("belonged_to").path().by(values("name","score")).by("name").toList())
```

error:

> NameError: name 'values' is not defined.  This is caused because by()
>   only takes a string argument.

How does one accomplish the goal of printing out multiple properties for test_score vertices.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track but you probably need to establish `values()` as a global function in python - something like:

```
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __ as AnonymousTraversal

values = AnonymousTraversal.values
```

Then once `values()` is available you'd need to slightly modify your `by()` modulator to terminate with `fold()`:

```
gr.V().hasLabel("test_score").
   out("belonged_to").
   path().
     by(values("score", "name").fold()).
     by("name").toList()
```

You need `fold()` to reduce the stream to a single value (i.e. a `List`).